# How to detect a user that is not logged in

Tags: cookies

Is there an easy way to see if a user - someone how has logged in in the past but is not currently logged in - is visiting my site?

I was thinking that checking if `$COOKIE[TEST_COOKIE]` is set, but I am uncertain.

1. Is this a good method?
2. Is there a better cookie to check for?
3. What would you do?

Comment: Hmmm ... TEST_COOKIE seems to disappear when session is over. Probably not a good idea. What do you think about checking to see if $COOKIE is not empty might be a better method as the wp-settings-time-* cookie seems to stick around for a year.

Comment: Are you using `$COOKIE` or `$_COOKIE`?

Comment: Was doing it right in the code ... not sure where the underscore went? I've abandoned this though.

Answer (score 2):

You could check for this cookie `wp-settings-1` it lasts for 1 day and then also check if `wordpress_test_cookie` is available.  Or you could just write a simple plugin that checks if the user is logged in and adds a longer term cookie to check against.